# Why github always creates "Merge pull request #xxx" merge commit when squash merging is off?

Tags: github, pull-request

```
master of main repo:    a -> b -> c
feature of forked repo: a -> b -> c -> d -> e
```

Assume a PR is created to merge commit `d` and `e` from feature branch in forked repository into `master` branch in main repository.

When the PR gets merged, if the squash merging is off, the master branch in main repository becomes:
`a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> merge commit f`

The merge commit `f` has title like `Merge pull request #xxx`, it actually is `d + e`, just like squeezing `d` and `e` into one commit.

So the master branch of main repository after merge is actually like this:
`a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> d+e`

Why would github create a "duplicate" commit that is actually `d+e`? And this behavior also applies when PR only contains 1 commit, after merge, a duplicate merge commit will still be created, like this:

```
master of main repo:    a -> b -> c
feature of forked repo: a -> b -> c -> d
```

after merge:

```
master of main repo:    a -> b -> c -> d -> merge commit e
```

Where commit `e` is as same as commit `d`, why we need a duplicate commit? What is the reason behind this? Thanks.

Comment: You want to do REBASE not merge. Merge does accumulative applies accumulative diff between branches so you will get a->b->c->(d+e with history)

Comment: That's not the graph resulting from the merge. [This is the result of the merge](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%7Ba-%3Eb-%3Ec-%3Ed-%3Ee-%3Emerge%3Bc-%3Emerge%3B%7D}. When you view the commit named `merge`, you see `d`+`e` if you compare to first parent (the default), which is `c`, and you see no change if you compare to second parent, which is `e`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes github, i updated my question.

Comment: @Antoniossss Sorry I didn't describe my question clearly, actually `feature` branch is in forked repository and `master` branch is in main repository. Thus a PR is needed.